# Android GCM Notification Arriving On Device But Not Displayed

Tags: android, google-cloud-messaging

I'm firing a message at GCM and it arrives on my device since I see logging on Android Studio Console.

The message as it goes out from my server has the format:

```
{
    "to": "fsfsdfsdfsadf",
    "notification": {
        "title": "Alert Title",
        "body": "Alert body with detailed description.",
        "icon": "@drawable/ic_launcher"
    },
    "data": {
        "title": "custom",
        "user-id": "123",
        "user-age": "44",
        "parameters": [{
            "parameter": "1"
        }]
    }
}
```

I have a very similar thing on iOS where the displaying of the notification is handled by the OS and then when a user taps on the notification a method is called where I do further processing, namely I use the 'data' key.

```
{
    "aps": {
        "alert": {
            "title": "Alert Title",
            "body": "Alert body with detailed description."
        },
        "content-available": false
    },
    "data": {
        "title": "custom",
        "user-id": "123",
        "user-age": "44",
        "parameters": [{
            "parameter": "1"
        }]
    }
}
```

My understanding, perhaps incorrectly, is that if I include the 'notification' key in my message then Android will display the notification in the System Tray; just like on iOS the operating system will display the notification if you include the 'alert' key.

Am I correct?

Comment: Did you add code to display this notification?

Comment: Yes I have logging but my understanding is that when a message arrives that contains the 'notification' field the OS will display the message and I shouldn't have to do anything. Currently I'm using the old messaging API on the device namely play-services-gcm-11.0.2 and I'm extending GcmListenerService. I created a new project that uses the newer Firebase API's (firebase-messaging:11.0.4 and extend FirebaseMessagingService) and that all seems to work as I expect it. So it appears like either I'm not implementing the old GCM stuff correctly or it does not support this.

Comment: In this documentation (https://developers.google.com/cloud-messaging/downstream) it literally says that the OS should show a message when 'notification' field is present. This is literally out of my control which would imply that I cannot mess it up.

Comment: No, OS will not show a message in notification bar until you write code to handle message(maybe json or plain text belong to your define) and send notification to notification area. Kindly take a look at NotificationManager class https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/NotificationManager.html

Comment: @khaintt But google documentation says the exact opposite "When your app is in the background, Android directs messages with notification to the system tray". Am I misinterpreting this? If so what method gets called when the remote notification arrives?

Comment: Maybe you are misinterpreting between Google Cloud Message(GCM) and Firebase Cloud Message(FCM). You implemented FCM notification on backend but it seem you are using GCM on android?

Comment: The message format for GCM is different then FCM on the back end? I've been unable to find any documentation that shows it's different.

Comment: It is about client side. If you use FCM lib, it will handle notification on background. But if you use GCM lib, you need implement by your self. So let implement FCM on client side and implement FCM on backend also instead GCM.

Comment: "GCM automatically displays the message to end user devices on behalf of the client app." That is a quote from the GCM documents here: https://developers.google.com/cloud-messaging/concept-options#payload. Am I looking at the wrong documentation? I also noticed that when I fire a Remote Notification to a device I get an error "EnhancedIntentService: binding to the service failed" on the device and my onMessageReceived() never gets called regardless of what state my app is in. Maybe everything is right but I'm missing a critical step on the device to put this all together?

Answer (score 0):

> Notification messages are delivered to the notification tray when the app is in the background. For apps in the foreground, messages are handled by these callbacks, onMessageReceived() in case of android

If you are app is in foreground you need to handle the display of notification, OS will only display the notification if app is in background. Refer to the [official documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/concept-options) for more details.